# <google-chart> into polymer <paper-drawer-panel>

Tags: html, charts, polymer

I tried to put a `<google-chart>` into polymer `<paper-drawer-panel>` but the chart does not appear.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong because if i try to put the chart without the polymer `<paper-drawer-panel>` the chart appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Google Charts in Polymer</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/google-chart/google-chart.html">
  </head>
  <body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <template>
      <paper-drawer-panel id="paperDrawerPanel" force-narrow>
        <paper-scroll-header-panel drawer fixed>
            <paper-toolbar id="drawerToolbar">
              <span class="paper-font-title">Menu</span>
            </paper-toolbar>

            <!-- Drawer Content -->
            <paper-menu class="list" attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="[[route]]">
              <a href="../#!/home">
                <iron-icon icon="home"></iron-icon>
                <span>Inicio</span>
              </a>   

              <a href="../#!/menu1">
                <iron-icon icon="shopping-basket"></iron-icon>
                <span>Menu 1</span>
              </a>

              <a href="../#!/menu2">
                <iron-icon icon="shopping-cart"></iron-icon>
                <span>Menu 2</span>
              </a>

              <a href="../#!/menu-3">
                <iron-icon icon="view-quilt"></iron-icon>
                <span>Menu 3</span>
              </a>

            </paper-menu>
          </paper-scroll-header-panel>

          <!-- Main Area -->
          <paper-scroll-header-panel main condenses keep-condensed-header>

            <!-- Main Toolbar -->
            <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
              <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
              <span class="flex"></span>

              <!-- Toolbar icons -->
              <paper-icon-button icon="search"></paper-icon-button>
              <paper-icon-button icon="account-circle"></paper-icon-button>

              <!-- Application name -->
              <div class="middle middle-container center horizontal layout">
                <div class="app-name">Polymer Charts</div>
              </div>

            </paper-toolbar>
            <div id="demo">
              <h1>Material Design</h1>

                <google-chart
                  type='pie'
                  options='{"title": "Distribution of days in 2001H1"}'
                  cols='[{"label": "Month", "type": "string"},{"label": "Days", "type": "number"}]'
                  rows='[["Jan", 31],["Feb", 28],["Mar", 31],["Apr", 30],["May", 31],["Jun", 30]]'>
                </google-chart>

            </div>
        </paper-scroll-header-panel>
      </paper-drawer-panel>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to put a `<google-chart>` into polymer `<paper-drawer-panel>` but the chart does not appear.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong because if i try to put the chart without the polymer `<paper-drawer-panel>` the chart appear.

Comment: Have you tried doing what was proposed as an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31939194/google-chart-not-displaying)?

Comment: Your chart is inside a `<template>` so that's likely the reason